# Absolute convergence of an complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I would like to show that the integral $$I(t)=\int_{B-i\infty}^{B+i\infty}\left|at^2+\frac{M}{4a}\right|^{-(1+s)}|e^{2\pi nt}|dt$$ converges for $\Re(s)>-\frac{1}{2},B>0, a\in \mathbb{Z}, n,M\in \mathbb{N}$ and satisfies an uniform estimate. Unfortunately, I do not know how to start, because I did not find anything about the convergence of a complex integral. Furthermore, I am not sure what is meant by uniform estimate meaning from what is the estimate independent. Note that I do not need the evaluation of the integral. I am thankful for every help and hint.

Using the tip I got \begin{align*}I(t)&=i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|aB^2+2aBix-x^2+\frac{M}{4a}\right|^{-(1+s)}\underbrace{|e^{2\pi n ix}|}_{=1}|e^{2\pi nB}|dx\\&= i|e^{2\pi nB}|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|-x^2+2aBix+aB^2+\frac{M}{4a}\right|^{-(1+s)}dx.\end{align*} I would say that the integrand is of order $O(x^{-2-s})$. However, I am not sure how to formally show that this integral is now convergent since it is still over the whole real line.

Comment: Try changing variables $t = B + i x$ so it becomes an integral over the real line.

Comment: Hi, I tried the changing of variables and edited it in the question. Was this the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrand is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and  $O(|x|^{-2(1-\Re{s})})$ when $x\gg 1$ which is integrable because the exponent is $>1$ this concludes your argument

Comment: The function is continuous. So on any finite domain the function is integrable. What matters is domination for large $|x|$